# stuck in a while loop c

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am doing an assignment for my C++ class. In this assignment I need to write a program that reads numbers from cin and then sums them, stopping when 0 has been entered using while loops.

I have written the code and gotten the results I need. However I am stuck in a while loop that continues to reprint the results. Can anyone give me some advice to end this loop after printing the results once?

Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{
int i(1), sum(0);
int sum2(0);
const int max(10);

cout << "Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:" << endl;

while (i!=0)
{
    cin >> i; 
    sum += i; //add current value of i to sum
    sum2 += 1;
}
while (i==0)
{   
    if (sum < 100) // If total is less than 100
        cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                 << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl
                 << "The total is less than 100." << endl ;
    else // Else total is greater than 100
            cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                 << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl 
                 << "The total is greater than 100." << endl ;
}
} //End of Int Main
```

Hopefully that came out alright. Sorry I am not sure how to post with the numbers on each line. I also tried changing the while (i==0) to an if statement if (i==0) but this closes the program when 0 is entered. Anyone have and helpful advice? I would appreciate it. ^_^

Update: Sorry I forgot to mention that I also have to include a loop counter that keeps track of the number of inputs, a comment that determines if the total value is less than or greater than 100, and a statement to determine the total number of inputs. That's the reason for the if else statement at the end. I have tried taking out the last while statement because I understand it is the reason for the infinite loop, but then it doesn't display the results when I do. I changed the code to this:

```
int main ()
{
    int i(1), sum(0);
    int sum2(0);
    const int max(10);

cout << "Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:" << endl;

    while (i!=0)
    {
        cin >> i; 
        sum += i; //add current value of i to sum
        sum2 += 1;
    }   
if (sum < 100) // If total is less than 100
            cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                     << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl
                     << "The total is less than 100." << endl ;
        else // Else total is greater than 100
                cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                     << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl 
                     << "The total is greater than 100." << endl ;

} //End of Int Main
```

my output is supposed to be

```
Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:
7
8
6
5
5
9
8
0
Thank you. The total was 48.
The total number of inputs read: 8
The total is less than 100.
```

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete, so please don't use it. Anyway, I have a small suggestion based on just this code: Change the final if-else to one set of outputs and use the ternary conditional operator to output "greater" or "less" based on the comparison. If the operator doesn't suit your fancy, change the bodies of the if-else part to just `std::cout << "greater";` and `std::cout << "less";` and put the other output parts outside. This is for removing unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: Why do you have a `while (i==0)` loop? You *know* `i` is zero, and you don't want to loop. (Also, the loop above that increments `i` one too many times.)

Comment: If you are stuck in a while loop check the condition that breaks the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your second `while loop` you are looping `while (i==0)` but `i` is never changed inside the loop.

```
while (i==0)  // Infinite loop, i is never change inside the block. 
{   
    if (sum < 100)    // If total is less than 100
        cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                 << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl
                 << "The total is less than 100." << endl ;
    else            // Else total is greater than 100
            cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
                 << "The total number of inputs reads: " << sum2 << endl 
                 << "The total is greater than 100." << endl;
}
```

The looping construct isn't needed at all here.

**Edit:** What you want is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  int i, sum, count;

  cout << "Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:" << endl;

  while (i!=0) {
    cin >> i; 
    sum += i;
    count++;
  }   

  cout << "Thank you. The total was " << sum << endl 
       << "The total number of inputs reads: " << count << endl;

  if (sum < 100)
    cout << "The total is less than 100." << endl;
  else
    cout << "The total is greater than 100." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Demo:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:
1000
100
10
0
Thank you. The total was 1110
The total number of inputs reads: 4
The total is greater than 100.

$ ./a.out 
Enter numbers, one per line. Enter 0 to end:
1
2
3
0
Thank you. The total was 6
The total number of inputs reads: 4
The total is less than 100.
```

Notice that the count includes the terminating `0` so you might want to report `count-1` instead.

Comment: I removed the while loop but now the program quits when 0 is inputted. I posted to new code. I am not sure if I am missing something or just did it wrong.

Comment: That looks great! thank you I will give that a try. I appreciate the help! ^_^ It definitely makes a lot more sense that way.

Comment: Sorry will do. It is still not printing out for me though. I wrote the code like you have it but it is not printing the results.

Comment: Once 0 is entered it closes the program window.

Comment: Never mind I restarted the program and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help! ^_^

Comment: That isn't a problem of C++, but of your operating system or windowing environment. To run a console program and see all its output, open a command line console and start the program there, by typing its name/path.

Comment: This is not due to the c++ but is a property of your environment, I guess your on Windows using Visual Studios so either set the option to make sure application don't close as soon as finished or add `system("pause");` and the end of the code.

Answer (score 2):

`i` stays stuck at `0` and never changes after you have exited your first loop.  Instead of using another `while` loop, just print the results afterwards.

Comment: Is there something I am missing in the new code that is causing it to quit rather than print the results?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `while (i==0)`.  That will always be true.